# IMS-LTI Gem documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, lti

This is not a programming question, but I still thought that this was the best forum to ask this question.

Is there any documentation for [IMS-LTI](https://github.com/instructure/ims-lti) gem? I have to create an LTI 2 tool in ROR but I am unable to find any documentation of how to use this gem? I know one way is to dig through [this example](https://github.com/instructure/lti_tool_provider_example) but can someone point me to the right direction? Probably someone who went through the same process, how did you learn how to use it? I have been searching for last couple of days but I could not find any thing.

Thank you

Comment: I see you posted a question in the project issues. Others have asked that same question there - such as [this issue](https://github.com/instructure/ims-lti/issues/121), in which people have pointed to these example apps: [1](https://github.com/instructure/lti2_reference_tool_provider) [2](https://github.com/instructure/lti_originality_report_example). In fact, there are [quite a few](https://github.com/instructure?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=lti&type=&language=) example applications by this author. I don't know if there is any documentation, but there's certainly plenty of information available.

Comment: The first example doesn't use this gem, as pointed in the answer on that issue... But thanks anyway, I think the second example will help... I believe I will have to go through the codes of projects..

Comment: I recommend reading up on the differences that LTI 2 has over LTI and how to use `ims-lti` will make a little more sense (https://www.imsglobal.org/lti-v2-introduction). You use `ims-lti` the same you would LTI, the major difference between LTI 2 and LTI is the application registration flow, beyond that it is no different. The models that will be of interest will be `lib/ims/lti/models/messages/registration_request.rb` and `/lib/ims/lti/models/messages/tool_proxy_update_request.rb`. all-in-all the library isn't doing much but helping to generate the necessary requests.